# Return the comment for non deleted posts

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

How can i get only the locations for the non soft deleted merchants.

- I have `Location` and `Merchant` models.
- each merchant has many locations.

when i get the locations :

```
$locations = \App\Location::where('merchant_id', $merchantId)->get();
```

it returns locations even if the merchant is soft deleted !

How can i prevent that, so it won't return the locations if the merchant is soft deleted  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Location` must implement `belongsTo()` to `Merchant`. Then add `has()` condition to the query.

```
$locations = \App\Location::where('merchant_id', $merchantId)
    ->has('merchant')
    ->get();
```